# C# - Logistic Curve Fitting

Tags: c#, curve-fitting, accord.net, mathnet-numerics

Here is my problem, I'd like to fit data in order to estimate the parameters of a Logistic function (perhaps 4PL and 5PL).

I managed it by using R and the package R.NET, however for licensing problem I can not use it in my project.

I see there are other free libraries such as Math.NET, Accord.NET.
Anyone expert on it that can help me?

Comment: Is this the only thing you want to fit? If you want a small and fast solution without license issues take a [Levenberg-Marquardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) and do it yourself. That's easier than it seems.

Comment: Yes, I would have preffered a more detailed answer. But I appreciate your help and will follow your hint.

Comment: Sure, that's why I made it a comment.